Frames of reference in Coriolis' equation
I feel like I should be able to work this out but keep confusing myself, so I thought I'd ask here.
Coriolis' equation (this seems to have different names depending on where you look) lets us find the derivative of a vector $\vec{r}$ relative to a frame of reference $a$ by taking its derivative with respect to an intermediary frame $b$ and using knowledge of the relative rotations of these frames:
$$\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt_{a}} = \frac{d\vec{r}}{dt_{b}} + \omega_{b/a} \times \vec{r}$$
This is useful when a derivative is required in frame $a$ but calculating the derivative is more straightforward in frame $b$, for example if $\vec{r}$ represents a point on an aircraft and frame $b$ is aligned with the aircraft's body.
Which frame of reference is $\vec{r}$ represented over here? Is it the same for all of the $\vec{r}$s, or frame $b$ for the ones on the right-hand side of the expression and $a$ for the $\vec{r}$ on the left (or something else)? I feel like this should be really simple, so perhaps there's a fundamental gap in my understanding somewhere...

The vector quantity $\vec{r}$ should be expressed in the rotating frame.
Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_reference_frame#Time_derivatives_in_the_two_frames.
